# Connecting a 2007 Mac mini to a Samsung Tv

Tags: mac-mini, television

I have a mid 2007 Mac mini that I bought to hook up to a tv and use for Netflix, tv, etc.

When I connect to the tv it shows a `mode not supported` message.

I followed the instructions on the web and I can remotely log in when it's connected, and it is running at 60Hz and I tried most of the resolutions all to no avail.

Has anybody had success connecting these two devices?

Comment: Connection type and any adapter being used?

Comment: It's connected at the tv with an hdmi and at the mac mini with a dvi.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.  After setting up a remote connection, I went through the video settings and it turns out the only resolution supported was 720p.  It was, by default, using something else that didn't work.